# Splunk : Adaptive Response Action is not generating logs

Tags: splunk

By referring this [document](http://dev.splunk.com/view/enterprise-security/SP-CAAAFBF) I have created one adaptive response action which I am able to see on Incident Review dashboards on "Enterprise Security" App on Splunk.

I have used same name for custom_alert_action_script (python file in /bin) which I have used to define action in alert_actions.conf.
In the python file I am using logger but it is not creating any logger file under "SPLUNK_HOME/var/log/splunk" directory whereas I can see log files for some of the adaptive response actions provided by splunk.
Also when I "Run" my adaptive response action, it should call the custom_alert_action_script defined under /bin directory but I guess that is also not happening.
I have used the same example as shown here http://dev.splunk.com/view/enterprise-security/SP-CAAAFBH

Can anyone help me on this?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue while working on a small assignment some time back and the issue was very small in my case.

Add-on should be named depending upon its purpose as mentioned in this link
[http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/ES/3.3.3/Install/ESArchitecture]

So I think your add-on folder name should start with TA (Technology Add-on) and it will work as it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Akanksha. 
Yes you answered it correctly. I made the mistake while naming the add-on but after following the naming convention it worked. 
Still thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake while creating Adaptive response action.
As I was working on it for the first time I didn't follow the naming convention which was the reason behind this.